# ArrayList<Double> cannot find symbol Java

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, double, java.util.scanner

While coding for my school subject, I had to fill an arraylist with Doubles, until I got the message "in", in which case I could stop and scan two other values, so I could start my calculation. Because showing the whole code is irrelevant, I will just show the Class in which we have the problem:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

class Test{
  double x1, x2;
  Scanner sc;
  ArrayList<Double> coefficients;

  void help() {    
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    coeffiecients = new ArrayList<Double>();

      while(!sc.next().equals("in")){
        coefficients.add(coefficient);
        coefficient = sc.nextDouble();
      }

      x1 = sc.nextDouble();
      x2 = sc.nextDouble();
    }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new Test().help();
  }
}
```

So, with this code, I get the error message: `cannot find symbol`

symbol: variable nextDouble

location: variable sc of type java.util.Scanner

I just don't get why this code should give an error. Can someone help me?

[[Added my code, still got an error on `ArrayList<Double> coefficients;`
Why is that wrong?]]

**The correct code is under here!**
*Changes are all described in answer no.1*

```
import java.util.*;

class Test{
  double x1, x2;
  Scanner sc;
  ArrayList<Double> coefficients;
  double coefficient;

  void help() {    
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    coefficients = new ArrayList<Double>();

      while(!sc.next().equals("in")){
        coefficients.add(coefficient);
        coefficient = sc.nextDouble();
      }

      x1 = sc.nextDouble();
      x2 = sc.nextDouble();
    }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new Test().help();
  }
}
```

Comment: `coefficient = sc.nextDouble()`

Comment: Please explain to the OP before you vote down. It is unhelpful to vote down without explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextDouble` is a `Scanner` method, not a field. You need to call the method

```
coefficient = sc.nextDouble();
x1 = sc.nextDouble();
x2 = sc.nextDouble();
```

Comment: @Richard That is unreadable. Please edit your question (link at the bottom of your question) and add that code and the details.

Comment: I edited it. Just the correct code as far as I was able to correct it.

Comment: @Richar `ArrayList` is a JDK class contained in the `java.util`. package. You need to import it. The IDE should already be telling you this. If you aren't using an IDE, consider doing so now.

Comment: You are really helping me out here. I feel really stupid. This is basic stuff. `coeffiecients = new ArrayList<Double>();` yet also gives me an error.
By the way, I'm using dr Java, because we should get to know things like this by heart.

Comment: @richard You've misspelled `coefficients`. Please go download and use Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans. Also `coefficient` isn't declared anywhere. How are you going to use it?

Comment: Finally got it errorless. I'm going to use the ArrayList for the coëfficiënts of a random n-degree polynomial equasion. The x1 and x2 declare the domain in which a root has to be found.

Comment: @RichardDirven Good stuff. Consider accepting the answer if it covered everything.

Comment: Don't know if you have read everything I said. But our assignments are always very specific. We aren't allowed to make the code 'error proof'. Later on, we'll have to do that actually

Comment: @RichardDirven What do you mean by error proof? For input, that's fine for now. But your program needs to compile and the best way to see that is with an IDE.